# How to specify the primary id when inserting rows with sqlalchemy when id dos not have autoincrement?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I do have database table that has an `id` primary key that is not an auto-increment (sequence). So it's up to the user to create an unique id or the insert will fail.

This table is not under my control, so I cannot change the database structure.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData
import psycopg2
db = create_engine('postgresql://...', echo=False).connect()
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=db)
t = Table("mytable", meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=db)
values = { "title":"title", "id": ... }#  ???
t.insert(bind=db, values=values).execute()
```

Comment: Is there a sequence associated with this column/table?  You can associate that sequence in sqlalchemy and it will do the bookeeping for you.

Comment: No there is no sequence associated with it. I guess the solution is to use `MAX(id)+1` but I have no idea how to tell sqlalchemy to do that.

Comment: Is this a multi-user system or mostly single-user? In case of latter, one could create rather simple factory method.

Comment: you should generally *not* use max(id)+1.  how are ID's assigned by the party that *does* control this table?

Comment: They are incremented, I guess they have similar approach of manually incrementing it. I did some tests and it is ok for me to add new numbers because they will always add MAX(id)+1. Yes, this is mostly single-user, the change of getting two inserts in parallel is less the one of having a hard-drive failure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this is "single-user" / "single-client" system, you should be able to use the [`Column defaults: Python-Executed Functions`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions). The example on the documentation linked to is enough to get you started. I would, however, use python function but with proper initialization from the datatabase adn still stored in a global variable:

```
def new_id_factory():
    if not('_MYTABLE_ID_' in globals()):
        q = db.execute("select max(mytable.id) as max_id from mytable").fetchone()
        _MYTABLE_ID_ = (q and q.max_id) or 0
    _MYTABLE_ID_ += 1
    return _MYTABLE_ID_


t = Table("mytable", Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, default=new_id_factory), #
    autoload=True, autoload_with=db,
    )
```